# How can I run my java class from the project root directory

Tags: java, cmd

I am compiling and running my Java project from the command line rather than eclipse for the first time and have a slight inconvenience that I just can't seem to find a solution too.

My project has a standard structure:

Project Directory

```
   /src

      /self

         /redway

            /myAPP.java

   /bin
   /libs
```

So I compiled using:

```
javac -sourcepath src src/self/redway/myApp.java -d bin
```

and so far so good...

I can run the program by navigating to the /bin and then just typing

```
java self.redway.myApp
```

BUT and this is really annoying. How do I run it from my project root directory?

I tried just

```
java bin/self.redway.myApp
```

and some other obvious ideas to no avail. I know it is a minor thing but it is super irritating and I'm sure there is a simple answer which I should have spotted immediately but I just can't find it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `java -cp` option to specify the class path. E.g.

```
java -cp bin self.redway.myApp
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a shell script like the following:

```
cd [your bin directory]
java self.redway.myApp
```

call this script for example runProgram.sh, place it in the directory where you want to be when you run your program, and run it using

```
sh runProgram.sh
```

that would also save you time if your program is going to use other jars and you have to add them to the class path, then all you have to do is change your java command in the shellscript to become

```
java -cp [path to the jar]:[path to another jar]:...:[path to your bin folder] self.redway.myApp
```